# Synergy 1.4.10 client config file and syslog entries

Tags: linux, synergy

Every few seconds I get synergy entries in my syslog as shown below.
How do I fix this?

And by the way, where if the configuration file for synergyd or how do I configure it?

I would like to reduce the logging to perhaps warning level.

(Mouse and keyboard works as intended. The reason for looking at this is that the linux-box went offline and these were the last syslog entries.)

I tried starting synergys and sudo synergys but it did not find a configuration file.
synergyd is running and does not return anything.

```
Jun 12 07:50:00 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:00 WARNING: failed to connect to server: No route to host#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,371
Jun 12 07:50:00 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:00 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,343
Jun 12 07:50:00 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:00 WARNING: failed to connect to server: No route to host#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,371
Jun 12 07:50:00 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:00 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,343
Jun 12 07:50:01 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:01 NOTE: connecting to '192.168.1.180': 192.168.1.180:24800#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,136
Jun 12 07:50:01 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:01 NOTE: connecting to '192.168.1.180': 192.168.1.180:24800#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,136
Jun 12 07:50:03 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:03 WARNING: failed to connect to server: No route to host#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,371
Jun 12 07:50:03 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:03 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,343
Jun 12 07:50:03 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:03 WARNING: failed to connect to server: No route to host#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,371
Jun 12 07:50:03 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:03 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,343
Jun 12 07:50:04 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:04 NOTE: connecting to '192.168.1.180': 192.168.1.180:24800#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,136
Jun 12 07:50:04 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:04 NOTE: connecting to '192.168.1.180': 192.168.1.180:24800#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,136
Jun 12 07:50:07 xy-Macmini Synergy 1.4.10: 2013-06-12T07:50:07 WARNING: failed to connect to server: No route to host#012#011/build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,371


$ synergys
2013-06-13T10:04:17 INFO: Synergy 1.4.10 Server on Linux 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:24:54 UTC 2013 i686
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,145
2013-06-13T10:04:17 DEBUG: opening configuration "/home/xy/.synergy.conf"
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,270
2013-06-13T10:04:17 DEBUG: cannot open configuration "/home/xy/.synergy.conf"
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,277
2013-06-13T10:04:17 DEBUG: opening configuration "/etc/synergy.conf"
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,270
2013-06-13T10:04:17 DEBUG: cannot open configuration "/etc/synergy.conf"
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,277
synergys: no configuration available
xy@xy-Macmini:~$ sudo synergys
2013-06-13T10:06:11 INFO: Synergy 1.4.10 Server on Linux 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:24:54 UTC 2013 i686
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,145
2013-06-13T10:06:11 DEBUG: opening configuration "/root/.synergy.conf"
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,270
2013-06-13T10:06:11 DEBUG: cannot open configuration "/root/.synergy.conf"
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,277
2013-06-13T10:06:11 DEBUG: opening configuration "/etc/synergy.conf"
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,270
2013-06-13T10:06:11 DEBUG: cannot open configuration "/etc/synergy.conf"
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.10/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,277
synergys: no configuration available
xy@xy-Macmini:~$ synergyd
```

Answer (score 0):

Start synergy with the flag for a lower debug level. Type `synergys --help` to see the usage.

```
-d, --debug <level>      filter out log messages with priority below level.
                         level may be: FATAL, ERROR, WARNING, NOTE, INFO,
                         DEBUG, DEBUGn (1-5).
```

I think the default is DEBUG, I had the same problem as you so I changed my startup script to

```
synergys -d WARNING
```

which is much more reasonable.